# Network wide padding issues in the sidebar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I've just noticed a padding issue in the [Linked posts sidebar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/98369/12615) at WordPress Answers:

[image: padding issue at wordpress.se]

I was about to report it in our Meta, but it has already been (regarding the Related sidebar):

> ### [Related Box Padding](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2430/12615)
>
> [image]
>
> *There's broken padding/margin on the bottom of the related box, Chrome 26 on OS X Mountain Lion*

---

Well, I decided to take a look at other sites and it happens elsewhere too.

#### [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/82/21950)

Related sidebar

> [image]

#### [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/9813/22453)

Linked sidebar

> [image]

---

Running OS X 10.7.4 and the issue is the same in all browsers:

- Firefox 20.0
- Chromium 25.0
- Safari 5.1.6
- Opera 12.14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, > rev 2013.5.20.1020.